# How to get child element of DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, css, dom

Trying to get the specific value from a table with `tr` and `td` elements...

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>value1</td>
    <td>value2</td>
    <td>value3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

PHP:

```
$html = 'http://www.example.com'; // edited

$dom = new DOMDocument;

@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$data = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr:nth-child(3n)');

foreach ($data as $datas){
        echo $link->nodeValue;
}
```

Using such or different approach, how to get the value of specific `td` element... ?

Comment: Why not doing it with JavaScript ? Btw, data is already plural and doesn't need a "s"

Comment: It's not clear which bit of this you're having trouble with, you've got a few different problems. `loadHTML` takes a string of source HTML, not a URL. You're not initialising your `$datas` variable. `getElementsByTagName` just takes a tag name, not a CSS selector.

Answer (score 2):

Using `getElementsByTagName()` returns a list of the tags based on your starting point, so once you've found the table, you can then use the same function to get the `<td>` tags.  You can then just pick out the elements your after...

```
$data = "<table>
  <tr>
    <td>value1</td>
    <td>value2</td>
    <td>value3</td>
  </tr>
</table>";

$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($data);
$table = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
$td = $table[0]->getElementsByTagName('td'); // Fetch all td elements in the first table

echo $td[2]->nodeValue;   // Echo out the value of the 3rd item (zero based arrays)
```

Prints out..

```
value3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how can I get it in action with 'file_get_contents'?

Comment: You can use http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php instead of loadHTML, saves loading to a string and then loading the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

`xPath` can be used to get particular element. Try the following code to get 3rd `td` value from given html.

```
$html = '<table>
  <tr>
    <td>value1</td>
    <td>value2</td>
    <td>value3</td>
  </tr>
</table>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$table = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(0);
$query = 'tr/td[3]';

$entries = $xpath->query($query, $table);

echo $entries[0]->nodeValue;
```

Read about [DOMXpath query()](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)

**Update:** Use of `file_get_content` is also simple, you can retrieve html/xml as string in `$html` variable and rest of the process is same:

```
$html = file_get_contents("path/to/file/x.html"); // target path
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but, I need it to work with 'file_get_contents'

Comment: @Gensus are you serious? All they did here for this example was replace `$html = file_get_contents(...)` with `$html = 'some string'` - and now you act as if this made it not an answer to your question …?

Comment: @Gensus Learn how to clearly formulate a question, with clear code examples. Your questions are all over the place and you keep moving the goal posts, by editing your original questions/code examples.

Comment: Thanks for your help too @DecentDabbler

Comment: @Gensus Answer Updated!

Answer (score -1):

I think this should help you.

Just assign class Name for td elements and then use this

for eg:

```
<td class="two">value2</td>
$(this).closest('tr').children('td.two').text();
```